# Change UIActivityViewController Edit button color

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller, tintcolor

I'd like to change the color of the `Edit Actions...` button at the very bottom of the `UIActivityViewController`.

```
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: items,
                                                      applicationActivities: nil)
```

This is what I was sure would be working, but it didn't:

```
activityViewController.view.tintColor = .green
```

These were further attempts. None worked as desired. The color didn't change.

```
activityViewController.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .green
activityViewController.tabBarController?.view.tintColor = .green
activityViewController.presentingViewController?.view.tintColor = .green
activityViewController.editButtonItem.tintColor = .green
```

What am I missing?

Neither SO, nor Google could help.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use below code while presenting activityViewController, I hope it works.

```
self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: { () in
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.systemBlue
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.white
})
```

Comment: Nope, this doesn't work for me (does it for you?). However I found the solution by changing the global tint color of the app. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68769156/3657691)